# Spring: Injecting Resource as InputStream into a factory-method

Tags: java, spring

I want to use anti-samy from OWASP.
They got a Policy object, that is instantiated via a factory method.

```
public static Policy getInstance(InputStream inputStream);
```

The InputStream that needs to be passed to the factory-method represents the config file for the policy-object.

Is it possible to use create a policy bean in an spring xml context config?
I know, that there is a Resource object, that can load files from classpath. But what I need is to make a InputStream out of that Resource object. Can I doe this directly in the xml-spring-context? Or do I need to write java code in order to get the InputStream?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the factory-method approach together with a constructor-arg (that will be mapped to a factory method argument) and automatically converted to an InputStream from a resource notation.

```
<bean id="policy" class="org.owasp.validator.html.Policy"
    factory-method="getInstance">

    <!-- type needed because there is also a getInstance(String) method -->
    <constructor-arg
        value="classpath:path/to/policyFile.xml"
        type="java.io.InputStream" />

</bean>
```

See the following parts of the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html):

- [Instantiation with a static factory
  method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method)
- [Built-in Property Editors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-beans-conversion) ([InputStreamEditor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/InputStreamEditor.html) is relevant here)
- [Examples of Dependency Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-some-examples) (last section is about `constructor-arg` used in the context of a static `factory-method`)

Comment: Hey, I didn't realise Spring could coerce to `InputStream`, that's neat. Note, however, that Spring will not close the `InputStream` itself, it assumes the bean will do it. If the `Policy` class doesn't close that stream, then you'll end up with a leak.

Comment: Well observed. Policy does not close the InputStream: http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/source/browse/trunk/Java/current/antisamy-project/antisamy/src/main/java/org/owasp/validator/html/Policy.java#210 . This should be reported as a bug, I guess

Comment: Hm, then I will open and close the InputStream in java-code.

However, the construct 
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:path/to/policyFile.xml" />
looks neat, but when I try it out, I get a FileNotFoundException, that tells me it can not find 'classpath:tempo-antisamy.xml'. Somehow the classpath prefix is not separated from the filename

Comment: @seanizer: I don't think this is a bug in `Policy`. It's good practise to close stream sin the same piece of code that opens them, and this would break that practise.

Comment: @nebenmir: obvious. It's trying to instantiate the method with the string parameter: http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/source/browse/trunk/Java/current/antisamy-project/antisamy/src/main/java/org/owasp/validator/html/Policy.java#158 I'll try to see what we can do about that...

Answer (score 4):

@seanizer's solution would be a good one if `Policy` closed the `InputStream` after it was finished reading from it, but apparently it doesn't. This will result in a leak, the severity of which depends how often it is called, and the nature of the resource.

To be safe, you should consider [writing a custom `FactoryBean` implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) instead, which handles the opening and closing of the `InputStream` safely. The `FactoryBean` would be injected with a `Resource` object.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for a singleton bean, but it could be a real mess in a prototype bean, I agree.

Comment: @seanizer: Just so. Also, on windows that's going to keep an open file lock for as long as the app is running, which can be a real PITA.

Comment: assuming it's a file and not a jar resource, yes